# Using MS Teams, is it possible to override the default notification text on mobile when sending a notification containing an attachment?

Tags: android, botframework, microsoft-teams

When a bot notification is sent to the user on mobile containing an attachment it mentions "[Bot Name] sent you a card" as follows:

[image]

The associated activity object in code is as follows:

```
Activity activity = new Activity()
{
    Timestamp = DateTime.UtcNow,
    Type = "message",
    ChannelId = "msteams",
    From = bot,
    Recipient = user,
    Summary = "Test Notification!",
    Attachments = new List<Attachment>() { cardAttachment } //cardAttachment is an object of type Attachment containing an adaptive card
};
```

Using the Summary property works on Desktop (i.e. it replaces the toast popup with the default “[Bot Name] sent you a card” message with the Summary content) but not on mobile. If it worked on mobile, this'd be just what I need.

Using the Text property on the Activity object is the closest thing to a workaround but it sends a second notification in addition to the first.

Is this possible to do? I'd appreciate any help with this, thanks!

Comment: This feature is not currently supported on mobile. We are working on it but we do not have an ETA to share with you.

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT Thank you. Is there any place I could check periodically to determine whether this feature is part of an upcoming release?

Comment: @Gousia-MSFT any updates? Showing "card" in the notification is not useful at all. If a user cant tell what the notification is about, they will not act on them, then why subscribe to them?